# How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout with FastCGI on Nginx

Tags: configuration, nginx, fastcgi

I am running Django, FastCGI, and Nginx.  I am creating an api of sorts that where someone can send some data via XML which I will process and then return some status codes for each node that was sent over.

The problem is that Nginx will throw a 504 Gateway Time-out if I take too long to process the XML -- I think longer than 60 seconds.

So I would like to set up Nginx so that if any requests matching the location /api will not time out for 120 seconds.  What setting will accomplish that.

What I have so far is:

```
    # Handles all api calls
    location ^~ /api/ {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

Edit: What I have is not working :)

Comment: You can set timeout values to "2m" instead of "120".

Comment: It seems bad that the data is not being streamed... ie for a server to start responding back in 60 seconds or more seems unacceptable.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Proxy timeouts are well, for proxies, not for FastCGI...

The directives that affect FastCGI timeouts are `client_header_timeout`, `client_body_timeout` and `send_timeout`.

**Edit**: Considering what's found on nginx wiki, the [send_timeout directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_send_timeout) is responsible for setting general timeout of response (which was bit misleading). For FastCGI there's `fastcgi_read_timeout` which is affecting the [FastCGI process response timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout).

Comment: For anyone using uwsgi and having this error, uwsgi_read_timeout 600; fixed my problem.

Comment: My question here would be (as a server admin amateur) where do I go to change this? httpd.conf file?

Comment: If it helps, mine was at /etc/nginx/  at Media Temple's DV system.

Comment: Abdo gives a nice way to debug. If you still have trouble, you might need to increase the max client message size in nginx.conf (client_max_body_size **M;)

Comment: Increasing the timeout imho is not a proper solution.

Comment: Yes, uwsgi_read_timeout 600; fixed my problem too in: flask + uwsgi + nginx

Answer (score 25):

For those using nginx with unicorn and rails, most likely the timeout is in your `unicorn.rb` file

put a large timeout in unicorn.rb

```
timeout 500
```

if you're still facing issues, try having fail_timeout=0 in your upstream in nginx and see if this fixes your issue. This is for debugging purposes and might be dangerous in a production environment.

```
upstream foo_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Comment: I think that people downvoted it because this is about Django, however your answer fixed my gateway timeout issue with Rails + Unicorn :)

Answer (score 9):

**In `http` nginx section (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) add or modify:**

```
keepalive_timeout 300s
```

**In `server` nginx section (/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-config-file.com) add these lines:**

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
fastcgi_buffers 8 1600k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 3200k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
```

**In `php` file in the case 127.0.0.1:9000 (/etc/php/7.X/fpm/pool.d/www.conf) modify:**

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Would anything "bad" happen if I change the time to 10000 seconds?

Comment: Not happen nothing bad, but your service wait more time. You can change it value as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use unicorn.

Look at `top` on your server. Unicorn likely is using 100% of CPU right now.
There are several reasons of this problem.

- You should check your HTTP requests, some of their can be very hard.
- Check unicorn's version. May be you've updated it recently, and something was broken.

Answer (score 1):

In server proxy set like that

```
location / {

                proxy_pass http://ip:80;                

                proxy_connect_timeout   90;
                proxy_send_timeout      90;
                proxy_read_timeout      90;

            }
```

In server php set like that

```
server {
        client_body_timeout 120;
        location = /index.php {

                #include fastcgi.conf; //example
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;//example veriosn

                fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
       }
}
```