# 504 Gateway Time-out partial problem

Tags: drupal, timeout, nginx

My problem is that I get this error for each fifth request or so; it happens on [this website](http://webdesignpatterns.org) when I (quickly?) open new tabs for each link in the sidebar.
Already tried everything including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by downgrading the Ubuntu version (because the problem appeared when I installed the newer ubuntu 10.10 64bit). I'm not sure though what was the real cause.
I saw others having same problem with Ubuntu 10.10.

After 3 days of struggling :) decided to "roll everything back".

Answer (score 0):

make sure the backend is not a bottleneck 
you could try to access the backend directly without the nginx in the front to make sure that if it's the backend 's problem.