# nginx/fastcgi 504 gateway error, increasing fastcgi_read_timeout isn't helping

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I need the timeout to be high so I can use a debugger on my source code.  It's getting passed to fastcgi from nginx correctly, but **always** times out after 60 seconds.  I've changed as many timeout parameters as I could find, restarted nginx and fast-cgi after every change and nothing worked.

I see most users point questions like this to [How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout with FastCGI on Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx).  But that solution did not work for me.

The parameters I've increased are:

- fastcgi_read_timeout (the above thread says this fixed the issue for
  that user)
- client_header_timeout
- client_body_timeout
- send_timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the `max_execution_time` value in `php.ini`?

That's the only other configurable value I can think of that might be causing a timeout.