# How to increase page timeout to prevent 504 error?

Tags: nginx, timeout, fastcgi, gateway

I am running a file with considerable amount of code and have to process it for 1000 users. It takes approximately 55 seconds to process 500 users, so I have to increase the default gateway timeout time.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx), I found that I have to increase `fastcgi_read_timeout`, but I don't know where to put it in `fastcgi.conf`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fastcgi_read_timeout` should be put into a location which you're using for processing requests to your file.

```
location {
     fastcgi_pass you.app:9000;
     ... 
     fastcgi_read_timeout 900s; # 15 minutes
}
```

Please, see more examples in [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_read_timeout)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is also to load parts of the page, for instance the list (or whatever) with only the names, and basic info. And after load do the rest with jquery and ajax.

Comment: if jquery available, that is.

Comment: Despite the existence of the word jquery, this is a much more sound solution than increasing the nginx timeout to some absurd value.