# Where is the fast-cgi configuration file for nginx, php.ini conf file located?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm receiving a 504 bad gateway nginx error. I've read plenty about this issue and all the possible causes. I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx).

I can't find the configuration file on my server.

I have tried `sudo nano /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf`, however, this is not the correct location.

I have also tried `sudo nano /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` with no success.

This is the output for `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     off;
    keepalive_timeout  5;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml $
    include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I want change the [fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout) and other settings, such as [fastcgi_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_send_timeout).

I've also read that it may be in `php.ini` too, however, I'm not sure where it's located.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to the nginx.conf file.

The way that works is that there are defaults for these directives. If a directive is absent, the default is used. To override the default, you specifically add the directive.