# Configuring nginx to prevent timeouts in Cloudbees

Tags: nginx, cloudbees

I have a long process in my cloudbees (roo + spring mvc) app that results in a timeout. According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx) a solution would be to change the configuration of nginx (in particular the  send_timeout directive ).

My problem is that I´m not sure how can I change this given the fact that I´m not self-hosting the application but using CloudBees for that.

Is this something that I can somehow indicate in the cloudbees-web.xml configuration file? (I haven´t been able to find a complete list of configuration parameters I can include in this file eihter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

You need to change your applications setting to have

```
proxyBuffering=false
```

when you deploy. This will allow long running connections. You only need to do this once when you deploy.

eg

```
bees app:deploy (etc) proxyBuffering=false
```

you can also use app:update to change an existing apps config (only need to do this once, it will remember it) using the [BeesSDK](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) - look for the section on app:deploy and app:update

Comment: I understand this would solve my current problem but is there any way to be more precise with the configuration, I mean, can I explicitly change nginx directives like the send_timeout mentioned in the question?

Comment: not at this stage - if you are using a SSL router then there are more options available - but I am not sure if it covers that. We have large uploads and timeouts using it all the time and it seems reasonable.

Comment: Note, we are working on allowing more directives to be set per application - so expect improvements soon !