# Nginx 504 gateway timeout after 60 seconds

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx)

I'm using an existing SOAP API for importing data via XML. Sometimes while the XML is too large I get a 504 gateway timeout after 60 seconds.

I've tried to set fastcgi_read_timeout to 300 in the nginx.conf but it doesnt work.
I've changed maximum_execution_time to 3600

Somebody an idea how I can change the timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup send_timeout because this specifies the response timeout to the client.

```
send_timeout 300
```

I think this is the case because send_timeout applies to client-read operations which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: After adding that I get Bad Gateway error.